# I am trying to understand what is happening in this variable assignment

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand what is happening in this variable assignment.

```
num = forward.Data.Key >= key ? 1 : 0;
```

In particular this part   `>= key ? 1 : 0`

To help out forward is a `LinkedListCell<KeyValuePair<int, double>> forward = _data.Next;`

`key` is an int parameter being passed into the method.

Also it is a program written in C#

Comment: Why the downvote? I know that this is a basic question, but ternary conditional operator is hard to recognise unless you know what it is, and hard to search for.

Comment: If you search stackoverflow for `c# question mark` it doesn't take very much perusing to find any number of duplicate questions, most of which are closed for being duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the ternary operator.  It takes a boolean expression, and returns one of two values depending on the result of that expression.  You get it in a number of languages.

It's equivalent to:

```
if( forward.Data.Key >= key ) {
    num = 1;
}
else {
    num = 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never heard consensus on the name of this thing.  Maybe it has different names in different languages...  Personally, I have always called it the *query-colon* operator, but apparently not many others do...  so I no longer use that phrase in my answers. =)

Answer (score 3):

It is called `ternary conditional operator`. (*or the short `If-Else` statement*)

```
value = condition ? truePart : falsePart;
```

The ternary operator tests a condition. It compares two values. It produces a third value that depends on the result of the comparison.

from MSDN,

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// if-else construction.
if (input < 0)
    classify = "negative";
else
    classify = "positive";

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input < 0) ? "negative" : "positive";
```

Comment: It's called the "conditional operator" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx